Question about Fulton’s “Intersection Theory”, example 8.4.6
In Fulton’s aforementioned book, after stating Bezout’s theorem, he states that a classical application of it is to show that an irreducible projective variety $X\subseteq\mathbb P^n$ of dimension $m$ and degree $d$ that is not contained in any hyperplane verifies
$$m+d\geq n+1.$$
The case $m=1$ is fairly simple : by taking a hyperplane $H$ passing through by $n$ points of $X$, it intersects $X$ in at least $n$ points. Hence Bezout plainly gives that either $d\geq n$, either $X$ shares an irreducible component with $H$ and hence is contained in it (because we assumed it was irreducible.)
Fulton says we can deduce the general case from this by “taking generic linear sections.” However, trying to prove it for myself, I seem to need the existence of a hyperplane $H$ which is spanned by points of $X$ and such that $X\cap H$ is irreducible. The latter is true of a generic hyperplane, but I can’t understand why the former should be.
To clarify, if I have such a hyperplane, $X\cap H$ cannot be contained in any hyperplane of $H$, and hence the inequality follows by induction.
However, dropping either assumptions on $H$, I cannot find how to proceed with the induction.
Does such a hyperplane necessarily exists? If so, why does it exist? If not, can someone give me a clue for proving Fulton’s claim without it?

Lemma. If $X\subset\Bbb P^n$ is an irreducible variety which is not contained in any hyperplane and $H\subset \Bbb P^n$ is any hyperplane, then the scheme-theoretic intersection $X\cap H$ is not contained in any hyperplane in $H$.
Proof. Consider the sequence of ideal sheaves $0 \to \mathcal{I}_X \to \mathcal{I}_X(1) \to \mathcal{I}_{X\cap H \subset H}(1) \to 0$ where the first map is multiplication by $h$, the equation of $H$. This is injective because $H=V(h)$ does not contain $X$. As $H^0(\mathcal{I}_X(1))=0$ by the non-degeneracy assumption, we have that $H^0(\mathcal{I}_{X\cap H \subset H}(1))\to H^1(\mathcal{I}_X)$ is an injection. But considering $0\to\mathcal{I}_X\to\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}\to\mathcal{O}_X\to0$, we have that $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n})\to H^0(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is an isomorphism, so $H^1(\mathcal{I}_X)=0$, and we get that $H^0(\mathcal{I}_{X\cap H \subset H}(1))=0$, or that $X\cap H \subset H$ is non-degenerate. $\blacksquare$
One may generalize to the case of connected $X$ by adding the requirement that $H$ contain no component of $X$.

Thank you ! I’m not super familiar with sheaf cohomology, and I’m not sure I see why non-degeneracy of a variety $X$ is equivalent to $H^0(\mathcal{I}_X(1))=0$ ?

Also I fail to see why $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n})\rightarrow H^0(\mathcal{O}X)$ is an isomorphism. Isn’t $H^0(\mathcal{O}{\mathbb P^n})$ just $k$ (the base field) ?

@SimonPitte I would recommend brushing up a bit on some basics of cohomology before doing more intersection theory, then. $H^0(\mathcal{I}X(1))$ is the subspace of $H^0(\mathcal{O}{\Bbb P^n}(1))$ which vanishes on $X$, and $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(1))$ is the vector space of equations of hyperplanes on $\Bbb P^n$, so $H^0(\mathcal{I}_X(1))$ is the vector space of hyperplanes which vanish on $X$ - by non-degeneracy, this is zero. Second comment: yes, that's exactly why it's an isomorphism - both sides are $k$ and the map is restriction.

Thank you ! I will definitely look into sheaf cohomology later, but I’m not actually trying to do too much intersection theory currently, I just needed it for other things and was curious about this statement.
